# How to clear session variables in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am setting session variable with this

```
$session->get('user_id');
```

I want to clear all session data or single variable. How can i do that

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Visit this link

http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#remove%28%29

`$session->remove('user_id')`;

Answer (score 11):

To clear all session data (attributes) you should use [clear](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#method_clear). Example:

```
$session->clear();
```

Please also see [Symfony session attributes documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#session-attributes).